# Storing generic JSON in Cosmos DB

Tags: json, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have number of JSON objects that I want to store in Cosmos DB, and they all share the same header, fields, but the remaining of the JSON are not the same, and at runtime I have no way of knowing the format. The JSON header fields contains fields such as Id, partition key and collection name, so based on that it should be enough to store it in the correct place.

From what I have tried in the dot.net client, the JSON needs to be serialized to an Object model to call the `CreateItemAsync` function, but I want to store the generic JSON. I have done something similar in Elastic Search - so is there a way to do this with Cosmos DB client also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize the JSON to a `Dictionary<string, object>`. Using that no information should be lost. Be aware to use the same serializer as the Cosmos SDK; Since it'll be used for serialization before sending a request to the CosmosDB. By default the current SDK uses Newtonsoft unless you specified a custom serializer.